# Is there any functions to get the specific content in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am making a company staff meeting attendance record form, now I want to through the function to directly get the data of staff in a specific date, but because the column of the data is not uniform, so the basic `Vlookup()` can not achieve this effect.
For example, I want to search the form by staff name to get the content of 1.24 (cell content contains 1.24). I would like to ask how to achieve this function and I would appreciate if u can help me. thank u!

***My record form is here:***
[image]

I've tried to do this by `Vlookup()` function but failed. It just can get the data in specific column. I want to get the data that contains specific date.

Comment: Where is Date in your columns ? Can you be more clear like what's your query and output you want to achieve. We can achieve this by creating a simple script for get api method. So it would be better to know your output and how you want to process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you insert your date in B19, you can erase your formulas in B20:B24 and use:

```
=BYROW (A20:A24, LAMBDA(each,IFNA( FILTER (INDEX(D1:Z12, MATCH(each,A1:A12,0)), REGEXMATCH(INDEX(D1:Z12, MATCH(each,A1:A12,0)),SUBSTITUTE(B19,".","\."))))))
```

Comment: Thank u so much. It works but how can i get a specific content. For examaple, i type "Ann" in A22, "Alcamisi" in A23, type, 1.24 in B1. i want to get the data of "Ann" and "Alcamisi" that contains 1.24. Would u plz help me? thank u

Comment: With this formula in B20, put "1.24" in cell B19 and Ann and Alcamisi in cells A20 and A21

Comment: sorry i've tried it but failed. I typed "1.11" in B19, but it said the there is no result in Filter function. [here](https://i.imgur.com/KrSr5T6.png) thank u

Comment: I've updated the formula. There was an issue with the "dot" in the date, interacting with REGEXMATCH. Try now copying the new formula! `=BYROW (A20:A24, LAMBDA(each,IFNA( FILTER (INDEX(D1:Z12, MATCH(each,A1:A12,0)), REGEXMATCH(INDEX(D1:Z12, MATCH(each,A1:A12,0)),SUBSTITUTE(B19,".","\."))))))`

Comment: OK. by the way, what do i need to change if the data is in another google sheet?

Comment: Change the ranges with [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

Comment: hi Martin! sorry to bother u but i have one more question: what if i want to search several sheets? i just know how to importrange one sheet. Could u plz help me with this issue? [link](https://i.imgur.com/hcnxLol.png)   IMPORTRANGE("Sheet1Key","SheetName!A2:A500");IMPORTRANGE("Sheet2Key","SheetName!A2:A500")

Comment: That would be OK, import with curly brackets. What I see there is that you've put all your ranges as A2:A500 instead of H2:R500 in the corresponding ones

Comment: Thank u so much Martin! It works very well. Have a nice day!